# Make a div stick to the top of another absolutely positioned overflow scrolled div

Tags: css, html, css-position

Here is the thing, there is a div `.page` which is absolutely positioned at tha page. Inside, there is a `.container` div and within the container there are the `.content`s.

The `.page` has certain heigth, so, contents would be scrolled inside the `.page`. In this situation I want a `.stuck` div to stick to the top of the `.page`. ( I am sure I made  grammatical mistakes above!)

Anyway, the fiddel:

http://jsfiddle.net/YBAvb/

**update:** I want the `.stuck` to be fixed at the top of `.page` regardless of the scroll on the `.page`.

this is the layout:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="stuck"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my (not working) css:

```
.page{
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.container{
    position:relative;
}
.stuck{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}
.content{
    height:700px;
    background:gray;
}
```

I want the blue `.stuck` div **always be there** at the top of the `.page` div. Any help?

**update:** 
note: a quick trick might be to make the `.stuck` be `positions:fixed` and the same position and width of the `.page`, but that is not my answere since the coordinates of the `.page` might change with JS any time.

Comment: Do you mean you want the .stuck to be appear (to viewers) at the top of .page regardless of the scroll on .page?

Comment: @TreeTree : Yes exactely as you said!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to fixed position an element to anything but the screen without javascript/jquery.

Comment: me too! :D This is the edge of css considering abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `.page` and `.stuck` to a common parent element and overlay the one over the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/YBAvb/1/

```css
    .page_holder{
        position: absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:200px;
        width:200px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .page {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:200px;
        height:300px;
        overflow:auto;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .container {
        position:relative;
    }
    .stuck {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        left:0;
        height:50px;
        background:blue;
        margin-right: 18px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .content {
        height:700px;
        background:gray;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="page_holder">
        <div class="stuck"></div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but the problem comes with the `.stuck` inside of the container. I can't bring it out in real case. Actually it would be like a navigation. It is in the middle of the content but it sticks to to top upon scrolling over.

Comment: I just scrolled and it doesn't stick to top on scroll.

Comment: @Si8 Looks like the one css class was missing from the snippet but was in the jsfiddle.  Added it in.

Answer (score 0):

> since the coordinates of the .page might change with JS any time.

**...so you already use JS! :)**

Using this exact HTML markup is **not possible**
For such cases we always have Javascript and jQuery: [JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OfiBeDU/1/edit)

```
$('.stuck').each(function(){

  var $that = $(this),
      $page = $that.closest('.page');

  $page.scroll(function(){      
    $that.css({top: this.scrollTop});
  });

});
```